# NSLayoutConstraint not working

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want the vertical gap between view1 and view2 to be 50, but both views appears in their actual position set by setFrame method. Anyone knows what i am doing wrong. Here is the code -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 50.0, 100, 50)];

    [view1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:view1];


    UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 280.0, 100, 50)];

    [view2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:view2];


    NSMutableArray * constraints = [NSMutableArray array];
   [constraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:view2
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:50.0]];
    [self.view addConstraints:constraints];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:constraints];

}
```

Comment: If you want to use constraints with programatically added views then you need to set the view's `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false`. You will then need more constraints to properly set the positions and sizes of view1 and view2

Comment: Thank you for replying, when i translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, view1 disappears. How many more constraints i need to apply, and what would that be for?

Comment: You need to set enough constraints so that the system can calculate an x,y position and height for each view. You have set the y position of view 2 relative to the bottom of view 1, but that is all.

Comment: Thanks buddy, i got that working now.